# binding parameters using the NOW function

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql, how do you bind the parameters when using the now() function?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, now());
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW()` is not a parameter of a query. Just put it like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname);
```

Comment: Ah, the problem is that there are too many "sss". Change it and it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` is a SQL function, not a PHP function. There's no need to create a bind parameter for something that is native SQL and doesn't need to be passed in.

You can just do something like the following:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname);
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing but it's not working (Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object)

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (username, comment, author, type, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $comment, $author, $type);

Comment: Sorry, wrong error message. This is the error message = "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables "

Comment: @thinkofacard You have 5 `s`s there are only 4 strings going in.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you directly call it like

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing but it's not working (Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables) $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (username, comment, author, type, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())"); $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $comment, $author, $type);